# Unable to install Postgresql-10 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, postgresql

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10
```

Comment: `postgresql-10` is available for 18.04 (*testing* or bionic) and not 16.04. please refer to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql

Comment: Or it's available through the PGDG repository. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Either of the first two comments would have been a valid answer to this question @guiverc (can only @ one person per comment)

Comment: @DanielVérité your comment could be elaborated into an answer; would you like to post one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess  Postgresql apt repository didn't added.

Add PostgreSQL apt repository

```
echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install PostgreSQL

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```

[ref](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

`postgresql-10` is available for Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e bionic) via standard repositories for installation.

Please refer to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql